# Heroku transfer data between remote databases, clear syntax example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a staging app full of data that I want to use to populate my currently empty production database. Currently I am trying to use pg:transfer. What is the correct syntax to use?

**Addresses:**

```
Staging app: afternoon-oasis-XXXX

Production app: warm-springs-XXXX, or postgres://long-database-url.compute-1.amazonaws.com:XXX/XXXXXXXX
```

**The documentation states:**

```
#documentation
$ heroku pg:transfer --to `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL -a app-staging` --confirm someapp
```

**I have tried**

```
$ heroku pg:transfer -t postgres://long-database-url.compute-1.amazonaws.com:XXX/XXXXXXXX -f JADE
```

This should be pulling from JADE, but the confirm message that appears to indicate that JADE, my afternoon-oasis app, my intended source, is going to be altered:

```
 WARNING: Destructive Action
 !    This command will affect the app: afternoon-oasis-XXXX
 !    To proceed, type "afternoon-oasis-XXXX" or re-run this command with --confirm afternoon-oasis-XXXX
```

Why would Heroku be altering the source database? Or am I getting the syntax wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The confirm flag probably goes on your production database. Just a heads up, I believe that when you transfer from staging to production using this method, it will overwrite your entire production database. So you could look lots of data.

Comment: I have a staging app full of data. My production app is empty. In this case, the flag is going up on my staging app, which I don't want to alter. I want it to pull from staging, push to production. In the future, it will be the opposite, but this is step one.

Comment: Clarified my question with those thoughts.

Comment: Gotcha. Figuring out the solution real quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Second Update**

You need the [pgbackups addon](https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups) for this but it is free. Sorry forgot that.

This addon will backup your postgres database every so often which is great if you ever need to recover data.

To add it just run `heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-week -a warm-springs-XXXX`

Also add pgbackups to staging app

`heroku addons:add pgbackups:auto-week -a afternoon-oasis-XXXX`

Then run

`heroku pgbackups:capture -a afternoon-oasis-XXXX` to backups the latest

Finally you can run

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL `heroku pgbackups:url -a afternoon-oasis-XXXX` -a warm-springs-XXXX
```

This command first gets the url of your staging app db backup and the pulls it to your production.

**Original**

Instead of using `pg:transfer` try doing something like this:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE_URL 'INPUT YOUR STAGING DATABASE URL' -a warm-springs-XXXX
```

Let me know if you've got any questions. Then you can just type the confirm message with prompted or add the `--confirm warm-springs-XXXX` to the end of the command above.

Comment: Getting '!    Resource not found'. Troubleshooting. Should I look into pgbackups:transfer?

Comment: Hmm my guess is that your production app doesn't have permission to directly pull from the database. You could add pgbackups to each which will allow you to do this. Let me revise my answer with the way to do this real quick.

Comment: pgbackups is installed on each.

Comment: Information was transferred. It was your second solution that worked for me. Thank you, that was a lifesaver!